# MCMCglmm: Posterior mean of modeled response variable

Tags: r, mixed-models

I would like to compare the modeled ("fitted") values for the response variable estimated using `MCMCglmm` with a zero-inflated Poisson distribution with the observed values from the data. Can anyone advise on a mechanism to extract the conditional mean values for the response variable from such a model? Essentially, I just want to calculate residuals using the observed data and the predicted values for the response variable from the model, but `predict` is not yet implemented for the data scale for zipoisson-family models in `MCMCglmm`.

```
require(MCMCglmm)    
example = data.frame(response=rbinom(10000,1,0.05), predictorA=rnorm(10000,100,10), 
                         predictorB=rnorm(10000,50,5), predictorC=rnorm(10000,1000,100), 
                         predictorD=rnorm(10000,10,1), predictorE=rnorm(10000,10000,1), 
                         randomA=runif(10000,1,10), randomB=runif(10000,75,90), 
                         randomC=runif(10000,800,10000))

pois_example = round(example,0)

gen_lin_mix_mod =  MCMCglmm(fixed = response ~ predictorA + predictorB + predictorC + 
                              predictorD + predictorE,
                            random = ~ randomA + randomB + randomC, 
                            family = "zipoisson", data = pois_example, nitt = 10000, 
                            burnin = 1000, rcov = ~ idh(trait):units, DIC = TRUE)
```

**UPDATE**

In Jarrod Hadfield's Course Notes file, there appears to be a "manual" method for calculating predicted values:

> In the call to MCMCglmm we specified saveX=TRUE and saveZ=TRUE
>   indicating that we wanted to save the design matrices. We can combine
>   these matrices into the design matrix W and multiply by the parameter
>   vector θ to get the predictions (See Eq. 2.9):
>
> W.1<-cBind(m4a.1$X, m4a.1$Z) # note X and Z are sparse so use cBind
>
> prediction.1<-W.1%*%posterior.mode(m4a.1$Sol)
>
> xyplot(weight+prediction.1@x~Time|Chick, data=ChickWeight)

However, when I try to implement this I get the following error:

```
design_mat = cBind(gen_lin_mix_mod$X, gen_lin_mix_mod$Z)
fitted = design_mat %*% posterior.mode(gen_lin_mix_mod$Sol)
observed = example

> design_mat = cBind(gen_lin_mix_mod$X, gen_lin_mix_mod$Z)
> fitted = design_mat %*% posterior.mode(gen_lin_mix_mod$Sol)
Error in design_mat %*% posterior.mode(gen_lin_mix_mod$Sol) : 
  Cholmod error 'X and/or Y have wrong dimensions' at file ../MatrixOps/cholmod_sdmult.c, 
  line 90
```

Comment: could you please give us a reproducible example?  (Are you sure you want to compare the mean and not the conditional mean?)

Comment: Example added. And, yes, good point; the conditional means are indeed what I want. Thank you for helping me to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Did you add `pr = TRUE` in addition to the `saveX = TRUE` and `saveZ = TRUE` options? If you did not, `gen_lin_mix_mod$Sol` only contains fixed effects and not random effects. That's why the dimensions are not right.